# Пересортировать массив

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Имеется два массива:

```
const array1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
const array2 = ['four', 'two'];
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как пересортировать array2, чтобы его айтемы имели последовательность, как в array1?

Чтобы получилось

```
array2 = ['two', 'four'];
```

Comment: Как бы вы это делали, скажем, на бумажке? Если распишите себе в голове алгоритм, то решение придет само )

Comment: В дополнении к предложению @SwaD , я помогу ещё намёком в виде одного слова - "индексы".

Comment: А поскольку массив константный - то никак. Если вы хотите его изменять уберите модификатор `const`.

Comment: @DmitryK константный массив напрямую нельзя изменить, но вполне можно изменить элементы с помощью индексов или функций. Думаю этого достаточно.

Answer (score 1):

Говоря про индексы в комментарии к вашему вопросу ещё до всех ответов, в которых господа отвечающие почему-то пошли по какому-то сложному пути, я имел в виду сортировку, основанную на индексах значений первого ("эталонного") массива. И выглядит это достаточно просто:

```js
const array1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
const array2 = ['four', 'two'];

array2.sort((a,b) => array1.indexOf(a) - array1.indexOf(b));
console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
const array2 = ['four', 'two'];
const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
    if (array1[i] === array2[j]) {
        result.push(array2[j])
    }
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

```js
const array1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
const array2 = ['four', 'two'];
const array2Len = array2.length;

for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < array2Len; j++) {
    if (array1[i] === array2[j]) {
        array2.push(array2[j])
    }
  }
}

array2.splice(0, array2Len)

console.log(array2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const array1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
const array2 = ['four', 'two'];

function sort (array1, array2){
  
  array1.forEach((array1Value,index)=>{ 
    if(!array2.includes(array1Value)) array1.splice(index,1)
  })
  return array1
}
console.log(sort(array1,array2));
```